# ExtJS data change event

Tags: extjs, grid, panel, store

What is the event that fires when the data in a DataGrid are recharged or rendered?

For example, a DataGrid showing the results of a filtered search. Every time you click on the Search button with a different filter, the results (number of rows) of the DataGrid are different.

Comment: The events render(this, eOpts) and afterrender(this, eOpts) only works at first rendering, however the followings render's don't fire the event method.

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do? You can add a renderer on each of your columns like this:

```
        {
            text: 'ChangedCaption',
            dataIndex: 'myBoolean',
            renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                if (value == true) {
                    return 'Y'
                } else {
                    return 'N'
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: I need to show off the table a text field with all values ​​in a column. So each time you realize a search and change data in that column, this field is also rerendered. So I need an event that fire when the data (Store) of the Grid Panel is rendered.

Comment: How I can obtain all values of this column? I think that this function only obtain the value of only one row.